# Как исправить ошибку RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exeeded

Tags: python, telebot

Создаю бота в PyCharm на питоне и тут ошибка. Вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'main', 'hello'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Путеводитель '))
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Найти авиабилеты ✈️',
                                                 url='https://www.aviasales.ru/?yclid=3526948572069625855&params=MOW1'))
    btn3 = markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Прогноз погоды ☀️'))
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'<b>Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!</b> <i>Я помогу распланировать твое долгожданное путешествие.</i> Нажми на одну из кнопок ',

parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'main', 'hello'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Путеводитель ', callback_data='Путеводитель ') # callback_data обязательна
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = InlineKeyboardButton('Найти авиабилеты ✈️',
                                url='https://www.aviasales.ru/?yclid=3526948572069625855&params=MOW1')
    btn3 = InlineKeyboardButton('Прогноз погоды ☀️', callback_data='Прогноз погоды ☀️')
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'<b>Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!</b> <i>Я помогу распланировать твое долгожданное '
                     f'путешествие.</i> Нажми на одну из кнопок ',

                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)
```